# gRaphael Script 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: css, xampp, raphael, graphael

I'm using the same code available [here](http://g.raphaeljs.com/barchart2.html), on my Xampp Server.
I've only changed the 3 script lines by this one's:

```
<script src="http://raphaeljs.com/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="http://g.raphaeljs.com/g.raphael.js"></script>
<script src="http://g.raphaeljs.com/g.bar.js"></script>
```

But when I do it, Chrome returns this message:

```
GET http://raphaeljs.com/raphael.js 403 (Forbidden) barchart2.html:8
Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined g.raphael.js:7
Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined g.bar.js:7
Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined barchart2.html:13
```

I tried some changes as loading the scripts from my server:

```
<script src="js/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="js/g.raphael.js"></script>
<script src="js/g.bar.js"></script>
```

But when a I do this, i face this annoying problem:

[image]

I've also changed the CSS lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://g.raphaeljs.com/demo.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://g.raphaeljs.com/demo-print.css" media="print">
```

Any ideas how can this problem be solved?!

Comment: how about the css file ? you included them ? does it work on jsfidle ?

Comment: The 403 is probably them deliberately blocking requests from other domains, because they don't want you to leech their bandwidth.

Comment: @Nick Probably... But when I load the scripts from my localhost server, I face that annoying problem, and I don't know why!

Comment: @Daniel here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/59wTV/2/ But I can't get it to work!

Comment: @Nick You're right! They block the request from other domains. I've uploaded the scripts to a server, and the error disappears. However, now I'm facing the bar chart number (on the image) problem on my server. Any ideas?

Comment: @zppinto, works for me http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/Q2Cjt/ , just add all needed js files

Comment: @Daniel Yeah... I already test it! This doesn't work on localhost as it should! I don't know why! Do you have the possibility to test on your server? I already installed 2 Apache servers, but I get the same results...

Comment: no server needed for this,  just make an html file on your desktop...

Comment: But I need it to my code, where I'm facing the same problem! Just try it on your desktop, you will see that the problem that I've have presented on that image, will happen to you as well.

Comment: works just fine locally, posted the entire code in an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version , a complete html file source... (used jQuery to load on *ready* of page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://raphaeljs.com/raphael.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://g.raphaeljs.com/g.raphael.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://g.raphaeljs.com/g.bar.js" ></script>

</head>
<body>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" defer>
$(function() {
   var r = Raphael("holder"),
                    fin = function () {
                        this.flag = r.popup(this.bar.x, this.bar.y, this.bar.value || "0").insertBefore(this);
                    },
                    fout = function () {
                        this.flag.animate({
                            opacity: 0
                        }, 300, function () {
                            this.remove();
                        });
                    },
                    fin2 = function () {
                        var y = [],
                            res = [];
                        for (var i = this.bars.length; i--;) {
                            y.push(this.bars[i].y);
                            res.push(this.bars[i].value || "0");
                        }
                        this.flag = r.popup(this.bars[0].x, Math.min.apply(Math, y), res.join(", ")).insertBefore(this);
                    },
                    fout2 = function () {
                        this.flag.animate({
                            opacity: 0
                        }, 300, function () {
                            this.remove();
                        });
                    },
                    txtattr = {
                        font: "12px sans-serif"
                    };

                r.text(160, 10, "Single Series Chart").attr(txtattr);
                r.text(480, 10, "Multiline Series Stacked Chart").attr(txtattr);
                r.text(160, 250, "Multiple Series Chart").attr(txtattr);
                r.text(480, 250, "Multiline Series Stacked Chart\nColumn Hover").attr(txtattr);

                r.barchart(10, 10, 300, 220, [
                    [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10]
                ]).hover(fin, fout);
                r.hbarchart(330, 10, 300, 220, [
                    [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10],
                    [10, 2, 1, 5, 32, 13, 20, 55]
                ], {
                    stacked: true
                }).hover(fin, fout);
                r.hbarchart(10, 250, 300, 220, [
                    [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10],
                    [10, 2, 1, 5, 32, 13, 20, 55]
                ]).hover(fin, fout);
                var c = r.barchart(330, 250, 300, 220, [
                    [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10],
                    [10, 2, 1, 5, 32, 13, 20, 55]
                ], {
                    stacked: true,
                    type: "soft"
                }).hoverColumn(fin2, fout2);
                });
</script>
<div id="holder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is actually solved, but only locally. And I can't run it on my server with this line '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://raphaeljs.com/raphael.js" ></script>'
When I change it from getting it from another server, or locally, same problem as on the image happens :(

Comment: instead of `src="raphaeljs.com/raphael.js"` reference the file as `src="http://raphaeljs.com/raphael.js"`

Comment: It's the same thing... Doesn't work as expected!
This is very interesting, but I'm starting to lose my mind...

Comment: You can see what's the problem on this [image](http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/8122/capturar2ed.png).
On the left is the raphael.js, from Raphaels website. However when you save it to your computer, it's "transformed" to the one on the right. And the one on the right, doesn't work properly, and thats what's causing my problem...

Comment: its just an ascii art with credits , try to remove them and see if it helps